# I want to run exe programs with a bat file. "Alarm Clock.exe" the bat file will be a basic short cut

Tags: windows

i want to run exe programs with a bat file. "Alarm Clock.exe"  the bat file will be a basic short cut but i will use the text to learn more about bat files. thanks for any help on this matter , it will help me learn a bit more about programing. Maybe with the whole text.
 D:\Program Files\alarm \Alarm Clock.exe
example

@echo off
start  D:\Program Files\alarm \Alarm Clock.exe
pause

im not sure

Answer (score 2):

Insert `Alarm Clock.exe` in the batch file with quotation marks.

```
"Alarm Clock.exe"
```

Reason for the quotation: There is a blank in the file name.

Comment: the whole text please im a beginner

Comment: This is the whole text ;-) Insert the code into the batch file and then start the batch file.

Comment: start "D:\Program Files\alarm\Alarm Clock.exe" brings up a CMD window. If i drag the exe file to the command window and hit enter it exicutes the program. What am i missing to make it a shortcut?....I'm just an average guy that knows almost nothing. Sorry for being such a pest.

Comment: "D:\Program Files\alarm\Alarm Clock.exe"
run/start

got it thx so much

Answer (score 0):

There's not so much to learn... to run a program with a batch file you just write its name (usually without extension), prepended by its path if it's not in the batch file's working directory or in the `PATH`.